# Having Whatsapp sharing url problem in Next js , i.e OpenGraph, Not showing or fetching data in whatsapp when using dynamic data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js, facebook-opengraph

When I am using meta og tags in _app.js its work with static content,
but when I use it on other pages like index , its not showing anything in whatsapp sharing

_app.js

```
<Head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"
    />
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
    <meta property="og:url" content={"https://connectme.co.in"} />
    <meta property="og:image" content={"https://images.wsj.net/im-515021?width=860&height=573"} />
  </Head>
```

its working here but in index page
its not working

index.js

```
<Head>
    <meta property="og:title" content={profileData?.name} />
    <meta property="og:image" content={profileData?.profileimg} />
    <meta property="og:type" content="profile.image" />
    <meta property="og:url" content={"https://connectme.co.in/"} />
  </Head>
```

profileData is ny dynamic data

now its not working here ,
when i Checked in facebook debugger its showing this

Inferred Property
The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Comment: What is the output for profileData?.profileimg ?

Comment: it is proper image url, data is not an issue , when inspecting its showing all og content correctly but still not displaying in whatsapp, you can see the live site here: https://connectme.co.in/jaiswar203 inpect it you'll find all og data, but it still not showing content

Comment: Where does `profileData` come from? Where do you fetch its data? Please share the full code for the `index.js` file.

Comment: @NILESHJAISWAR, did you find the solution because I am stuck on same issue

Comment: Yeah I created different backend route only to fetch resource which is useful and fetched it in getServerSideProps. This issue is because of when the whole page gets load then it fetch the data , OG can't fetch data after page load thats why I used fetching in getServerSideProps